# onclick="return confirm()" not appearing

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

```
<?php <td><a onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?')  href='Delete_Vendor.php?ID=$row[ID]' ;> Delete </a> </td> <?
```

This code is working fine for me but the alert of "Are you sure?" is not showing up. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if u need confirm() y r using href?

Comment: You need to `echo` the HTML to the output as a string. At the moment you'll be getting syntax errors.

Comment: You need to escape the string accordingly "return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')"

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to `echo` the HTML you have as a string to the output of the page. Secondly, you need to fix the quotes you have in the HTML. Attribute values should be delimited with double quotes (`"`). You can then use single quotes (`'`) within those values, although you will need to escape them when echoing from PHP. Try this:

```
<?php echo '<td><a onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')" href="Delete_Vendor.php?ID=$row[ID]">Delete</a></td>' ?>
```

A more succinct alternative:

```html
<td>
    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="Delete_Vendor.php?ID=<?= $row[ID] ?>">Delete</a>
</td>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/m57o0uwp/)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

In your example, you are missing the onclick() event ending quotes.

Second, you need to use `$row['ID']` inside the php tag.

**Working Example:**

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="Delete_Vendor.php?ID=<?=$row['ID']?>">Delete</a>
```

**Alternate Example:**

```
<td>
<a onclick="yourConfirm(<?=$row['ID']?>);" href="javascript:void(0);"> 
Delete </a>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function yourConfirm(id){
var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (r == true) {
    window.location = "Delete_Vendor.php?ID="+id;
  } 
}
</script>
```

```html
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="Delete_Vendor.php?ID=1">Delete</a>
```